# Nuvola Player - no sound under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10

Nuvolaplayer does not output any sound under Ubuntu 13.10. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and I note that on reinstallation, there seems to be an error:

```
create symlink to plugin in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins: failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

For certain services you need mp3 decoder which is not installed on ubuntu by default.

Depending on gstreamer version installed (you can check by dpkg -l gstreamer*) you need to install

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
```

or on newer systems

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
```

You can find whole description in Nuvola FAQ #2011 https://answers.launchpad.net/nuvola-player/+faq/2011

Comment: All of those are installed. The real problem seems to be the symlink error I mentioned.

Comment: Is directory /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins present on your system? If not, try to create it first.